# How to use queryString() in elasticsearch (java API)?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am working on elastic-search v1.1.1
I faced a problem with search queries .I want to know How solve below obstacle

Here is my mapping

```
{
  "token" : {
               "type" : "string"
            }
}
```

Data in indexed record is

```
 {
   token : "4r5etgg-kogignjj-jdjuty687-ofijfjfhf-kdjudyhd"
 }
```

My search is

```
4r5etgg-kogignjj-jdjuty687-ofijfjfhf-kdjudyhd
```

I want exact match of the record ,which query I need to use to get exact match of the record
can it be done

```
  QueryBuilders.queryString() ?
```

I checked with queryString() ,then I finalized its not useful for exact match

Please suggest me

Comment: try `token:"4r5etgg-kogignjj-jdjuty687-ofijfjfhf-kdjudyhd"`

Comment: `queryString()` returns either `4r5etgg` or `kogignjj` or `jdjuty687` or `ofijfjfhf` or `kdjudyhd` match. i want exact match like `4r5etgg-kogignjj-jdjuty687-ofijfjfhf-kdjudyhd`

Comment: Any reason why this got down voted (somebody down voted before)? It seems like they want to send people to paid forums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put quotes around the string to do an exact match:

```
QueryBuilders.queryString("\"4r5etgg-kogignjj-jdjuty687-ofijfjfhf-kdjudyhd\"");
```

If you don't want partial matches on the above string index an untokenized version of the value and search on that. In you mapping add:

```
"token": {
    "type": "multi_field",
    "fields": {
        "untouched":   { 
            "type": "string", 
            "index": "not_analyzed" 
        }
    }
}
```

Then search:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "token.untouched": "4r5etgg-kogignjj-jdjuty687-ofijfjfhf-kdjudyhd"
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: `QueryBuilders.queryString("\"4r5etgg\"")` and `QueryBuilders.queryString("\"kogignjj\"")` and `QueryBuilders.query("\"jdjuty687\"")` and `QueryBuilders.queryString("\"ofijfjfhf"")` and `QueryBuilders.queryString("\"kdjudyhd\"")`  are returning same record.I expecting exact match .

Answer (score 2):

Change the mapping so ElasticSearch doesn't touch your data while indexing like so to:

```
{
  "token" : {
    "type" : "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed" 
  }
}
```

And then run a TermQuery from java like this

```
QueryBuilders.termQuery("token", "4r5etgg-kogignjj-jdjuty687-ofijfjfhf-kdjudyhd");
```

That should give you your exact match.