# Search keyword using double quotes to get exact match in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

If user searches by giving quotes around keyword like "flowers and mulch" then exact matches should be displayed.

I tried using query_string which is almost working but not satisfied with those results.

Can anyone help me out please.

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
           "fields": ["body"], 
           "query": "\"flowers and mulch\""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697511/how-to-use-querystring-in-elasticsearch-java-api/24699291#24699291

Comment: It would be useful to know what aspects of query_strings you were not satisfied with

Answer (score 6):

You should be using phrase_match for exact matches of phrases:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "body": "flowers and mulch"
        }
    }
}
```

> **Phrase matching**
>
> In the same way that the match query is the “go-to” query for standard
>   full text search, the match_phrase query is the one you should reach
>   for when you want to find words that are near to each other.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html

Comment: This doesn't help for queries like `one "two three"` where a subset of the query should be treated as a phrase.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn You can create a `bool` query that combines a `match_phrase` query for "two three" and a `match` query for "one".

Answer (score 3):

As I put in the comment of the question, I think knowing what the OP found not satisfying about `query_string` would be great. I would recommend using query_string for these cases. Note that there are multiple options that could be set, such as: `auto_generate_phrase_queries`, `split_on_whitespace`, or `quote_field_suffix` (example: [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/recipes.html#mixing-exact-search-with-stemming)), which makes it quite versatile.

The case `one "two three"`could be addressed using default parameters of `query_string`